# Sending UDP and TCP packets on the same network line - how to prevent UDP drops?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I am sending tcp and udp packets to another computer over a wireless connection, using linux sockets in C. TCP packets are sent in chunks of 16KB in a thread, and UDP packets are sent in chunks of 512 bytes in another thread.

I can change the number of TCP packets per second.
When I set a low TCP frequency, I receive every UDP packets.
However, when I start increasing the TCP packet frequency, I start loosing many UDP packets on the receiving side. (95% packets loss when overall bandwidth uses as little as 20% of my wireless' real bandwidth (which is around 3MB/s) )

I know the UDP protocol is a send a pray mechanism, but I would expect to have a low rate of lost packets when the total network bandwidth is far from being saturated!

- This is not a duplicate of [Prevent TCP connections from causing UDP packet loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446302/prevent-tcp-connections-from-causing-udp-packet-loss) because my connection is not saturated
- I don't want to send the UDP data embedded in the TCP packets
- I don't mind if some packets are dropped

I have made a second experiment:
I launched a file transfer with samba while sending udp packets (going towards the target computer). The connection is saturated due to the file transfer (at around 3MB/s), but the UDP packet drop rate is acceptable (around 10%)!!

Why do I get so many drops in a non saturated environment when I'm sending the TCP packets myself? The difference is quite astonishing.

Thank you for your help!

Here is the way the packets are sent:
Initialization of the socket:

```
printf("Creating socket and listening on port %i\n",Params::tcpOutPort);
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0) 
    printf("ERROR opening socket\n");
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(Params::tcpOutPort);

int opt=1;
setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(const char *)&opt,sizeof(int));

if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    printf("ERROR on binding\n");
listen(sockfd,5);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
if (newsockfd < 0) 
    printf("ERROR on accept\n");
else printf("Connected!\n");
```

Sending a packet:

```
leftToSend = size;
while(leftToSend > 0)
{
    sent = send(newsockfd,buf+alreadySent,leftToSend > send_blocks ? send_blocks : leftToSend,0);
    if(sent > -1)
    {
        alreadySent += sent;
        leftToSend -= sent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting TCP_NODELAY or otherwise disabling Nagling? If so, that's your problem. How exactly are you sending TCP packets? (Most likely, you are doing something wrong in your TCP code, whatever it is.)

Comment: Nagling is not disabled, I will try to see if it improves!

Comment: Why are you trying to micromanage TCP this way? Do you think you can do a better job than the kernel?

Comment: If you're losing UDP packets your connection is indeed saturated somewhere.

Comment: do you know where they are getting dropped? If you can, use a 3rd machine to capture the wireless traffic in promiscuous mode. That will be a good check to see if they're even making it into the air.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. i've disabled Nagle algorithm, it didn't improve. I'll try sniffing packets to see if it reaches the router!